# frame of navigationitem titleView in viewcontroller view

Tags: ios, swift

How do I get the frame of a navigationItem's titleView in the coordinate system of the viewcontroller's view?

```
if let navBarHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height,
   let navBarWidth = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.width {
   myCustomTitleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: navBarWidth, height: navBarHeight)
   navigationItem.titleView = myCustomTitleView
}
```

However, when I check myCustomTitleView's frame origin, I get (0, 0).

I then tried to translate this origin to the viewcontroller's view. what I got was (0,-44), which accounts for the navigation bar height but not for the x-offset.

```
let originInVCView = view.convert(myCustomTitleView.frame.origin, from: myCustomTitleView)
```

This can't be right as the titleView obviously has an offset (space for the back button).

How do I correctly extract the translated titleView origin?

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure you have set the navigation item in viewDidLoad() first. Otherwise it will be nil.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "MY_IMAGE"))
  navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

When done you can get the frame in the VC's viewDidAppear where the view has been laid out:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

     let nItemFrame = navigationItem.titleView?.frame     //<<<---
}
```

Comment: it's not nil. i'm getting an origin, it's just wrong with respect to the viewcontroller's view

Comment: Great - just trying to make sure. If the navigationItem.titleView is properly initialized, you will find its dimensions in viewDidAppear as the vc has at that point properly laid out its subviews.